# How do you properly format this log?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, colors, text-formatting

So I am listening on netcat on a specified port and am saving the output to a logfile. Apparently the log file is a oneliner... How do I properly format it? Extra points if you incorporate grc or similar program which add colours and somehow smartly remove the included color codes:

## Input (by mistake this was processed by a sed script, please ignore the /\n/)

`[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},"2021-03-25T08:01:08.086Z","default",["6"],{"level":20000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{},"Hello, log4js! \n","INFO","green"]__LOG4JS__[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},"2021-03-25T08:01:08.096Z","default",["6"],{"level":30000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{},"Test warning! This is not a drill! \n","WARN","yellow"]__LOG4JS__[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},"2021-03-25T08:01:08.229Z","default",["6"],{"level":20000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{}/\\n/,"Connected to mongo","INFO","green"]`

## Output

```
[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},
"2021-03-25T08:01:08.086Z","default",["6"],{"level":20000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{},"Hello, log4js! \n","INFO","green"]__LOG4JS__[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},
"2021-03-25T08:01:08.096Z","default",["6"],{"level":30000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{},"Test warning! This is not a drill! \n","WARN","yellow"]__LOG4JS__[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},
"2021-03-25T08:01:08.229Z","default",["6"],{"level":20000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{}/\\n/,"Connected to mongo","INFO","green"]
```

## My try to accomplish this (please note it's incorrect)

`awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"__LOG4JS__")}1' a="$(ncat -l -k 10.0.0.1 10000)" log.log`

Comment: Can you install 'jq'? This looks like JSON.

Comment: I can. How can you parse it using `jq` in a logical manner?

Comment: Your output would be created by just matching the date sting and inserting a newline: `sed 's/"20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]\{3\}Z",/\n&/g'` - to match it as good as possible to avoid errors - post year 2000.

Comment: @icarus it's chunks of valid JSON glued together with the log4js end-of-message separator "__LOG4JS__" so it would need some minor pre-processing to do this. There's also an unparseable "/\\n/" literal which might mean indicate some other pre-processing has not had the intended effect.

Comment: @FelixJN Thanks, that appears to be part of the solution. How do I pipe it to a generic colouriser or smth similar? I prefer to colorise it and then save to a file and none of these appears to be working for some reason. I piped using `|` obviously. Colorization is optional, saving to a file is a must though. If you write that into an answer I will vote up and accept it as answer.

Comment: @mr.spuratic Sure has seen a better pattern. I think your desired output is not what you actually want. Rather use `__LOG4JS__` as record separator. That way it makes it three entries with the same makeup

Comment: @FelixJN I figured out how to colorize I just had to add grc before the command. A simple > also works to save it to a file (colors disappear but you can use grc on the file to colorize it again)

Comment: Is `Output` the output you want or the output you get that you don't want (and if so what does your desired output look like)?

Comment: `gsub(/\\n/,"__LOG4JS__")` is looking for the literal 2-character string `\n` and replacing it with the string `__LOG4JS__` which is close to the complete opposite of what you seem to want to do.

Comment: @EdMorton the output is an example of an okish output

Comment: So you WANT output that looks like that? What's the logic to transform your input to that output? I had assumed you wanted to convert `__LOG4JS__`s to newlines but apparently not.

Comment: Yes, but please keep in mind that your suggestion to format it in JSON is superior to my example. That's pretty much what I did, just that I added them at different spots. The only use of this is better readibility, I mean who likes long oneliners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to do but if it's just convert every `__LOG4JS__` to a newline than that'd be this using GNU awk for multi-char RS (I fixed your input to remove that spurious `/\\n/` that was present in the 3rd line making that invalid JSON and which I assume isn't actually present in your real data):

```
$ awk -v RS='__LOG4JS__|\r?\n' '1' file
[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},"2021-03-25T08:01:08.086Z","default",["6"],{"level":20000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{},"Hello, log4js! \n","INFO","green"]
[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},"2021-03-25T08:01:08.096Z","default",["6"],{"level":30000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{},"Test warning! This is not a drill! \n","WARN","yellow"]
[{"startTime":"1","categoryName":"2","data":"3","level":"4","context":"5","pid":7520},"2021-03-25T08:01:08.229Z","default",["6"],{"level":20000,"levelStr":"7","colour":"8"},{},"Connected to mongo","INFO","green"]
```

You can do the same with any awk but this will read the whole file into memory (as would an equivalent sed solution):

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,""); gsub(/__LOG4JS__/,ORS)}1' file
```

If you're trying to do something else then please clarify what that is and update the example in your question to show the expected output.

With the above if you just want to see formatted json output:

```
$ awk -v RS='__LOG4JS__|\r?\n' '1' file | jq .
[
  {
    "startTime": "1",
    "categoryName": "2",
    "data": "3",
    "level": "4",
    "context": "5",
    "pid": 7520
  },
  "2021-03-25T08:01:08.086Z",
  "default",
  [
    "6"
  ],
  {
    "level": 20000,
    "levelStr": "7",
    "colour": "8"
  },
  {},
  "Hello, log4js! \n",
  "INFO",
  "green"
]
[
  {
    "startTime": "1",
    "categoryName": "2",
    "data": "3",
    "level": "4",
    "context": "5",
    "pid": 7520
  },
  "2021-03-25T08:01:08.096Z",
  "default",
  [
    "6"
  ],
  {
    "level": 30000,
    "levelStr": "7",
    "colour": "8"
  },
  {},
  "Test warning! This is not a drill! \n",
  "WARN",
  "yellow"
]
[
  {
    "startTime": "1",
    "categoryName": "2",
    "data": "3",
    "level": "4",
    "context": "5",
    "pid": 7520
  },
  "2021-03-25T08:01:08.229Z",
  "default",
  [
    "6"
  ],
  {
    "level": 20000,
    "levelStr": "7",
    "colour": "8"
  },
  {},
  "Connected to mongo",
  "INFO",
  "green"
]
```

Comment: The awkward `/\\n/` is for some reason available in my raw data.. I have no clue why it happens maybe it's an misinterpretation from ncat's side...

Comment: It looks an awful lot like someone has written an awk or sed script to do something with the `ncat` output and is accidentally printing `/\\n/` (the awk or sed command to search for the string `\n` in the input, as used in the awk command in your question). It would be shocking breakage if `ncat` was injecting that itself. It's a trivial tweak to have the awk script in my answer remove it though (`gsub("/[\\\\]{2}n/","")`) if you can't figure out where it's coming from to stop it at the source and it's safe to assume it doesn't occur in any real data strings.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I jeopardized myself by copying from the wrong file. The raw data does contain `\r\n` though

Comment: That's no big deal. Do you want the output to also use `\r\n` line endings or just `\n`? For now I tweaked the scripts in my answer to accept `\n` or `\r\n` line endings as input and generate `\n`-only line endings as output.

Comment: What's the difference for this scenario when working on Windows machines (so PuTTY) with Linux Servers? I doubt it really matters, I personally prefer the Linux standard `\n`

Comment: Anything you run on Unix (including Linux) will expect Unix line endings (`\n`) while anything on Windows will expect DOS line endings (`\r\n`) and what any given tool does with the other format is platform+tool+application dependent. For example awk on Unix expects `\n` line endings but if there's `\r\n` line endings that just means the last field on each line will end in `\r` and the impact of that depends what you want to do with that last field plus on some systems the underlying C prims would strip the `\r`s before awk even saw them anyway.

Comment: See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for a discussion on that.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is well-formed JSON, which it's not, you could do this:

```
ncat ... |  sed -e 's/__LOG4JS__/\n/g' | jq -s -M .
```

`__LOG4JS__` is the [end-of-message separator](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/docs/tcp.md) so the `sed` converts it to newline, and then `jq`
to pretty-print (with `-M` to suppress color escapes and show just the JSON formatting).

The problem with the input is this: `{}/\\n/`  which cannot be parsed (third line).

I'm not entirely certain what you want to do with colours, this will remove the named colour strings entirely from the output (assuming green, yellow, red), and `-C` to colourize (usually the default for terminal output).

```
ncat ... | sed ... | jq -C '. - ["green","yellow","red"]'
```

Optionally add `-c` to compact the output instead of multi-line pretty print, this will be closer to your sample output.

(You might find some  parts of the output invisible depending on your terminal background – colours are hard-coded up to jq-1.5 at least.)

Comment: For some reason it doesn't print out anything... weird... any clue how to fix it?